# Second title of a plot/photo is the value of a column in a CSV but only the last value is used in all photos

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a script that makes a photo that shows a basemap and where an earthquake happened. So 1 earthquake, 1 photo. The second title of each plot should be the date of the earthquake. **However, only the last value, which is "2020-04-10", is used in all photos.**

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.chdir(r'path')

def plotPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv('earthquakes.csv')
    basemap = gpd.read_file('basemap.shp')
    crs = "epsg:32651"
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
    for d in df['Date'].values:
        date = d
    for i in range(gdf.shape[0]): 
        ax = basemap.plot(figsize=(15,10)) 
        ax.axis('off')
        g = gdf.iloc[i].geometry           
        plt.plot(g.x, g.y, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
        title = 'Earthquakes in the ___ from 2008 to 2020'
        dateInfo = str(date)
        plt.suptitle(title)
        plt.title(dateInfo)
        plt.savefig("earthquake_{0}.png".format(i))

plotPoint()
```

Get the values of "Date" column

```
for i in df['Date'].values:
    print(i)
```

Result

```
2020-04-22
2020-04-22
2020-04-21
2020-04-18
2020-04-10
```

Sample CSV

```
Latitude,Longitude,Date,Time_UTC,Depth,Depth Type,Magnitude Type,Magnitude,Region Name,Last Update,Eqid,unknown field
13.81,121.1,2020-04-22,03:19:57,10,f,mb,4.5,MINDORO, PHILIPPINES,2020-04-28 23:17,850323
13.76,120.92,2020-04-22,02:36:19,10, , M,4.2,MINDORO, PHILIPPINES,2020-04-22 03:50,850325
10.45,125.2,2020-04-21,21:43:05,10,f,mb,4.7,LEYTE, PHILIPPINES,2020-04-21 22:55,850252
6.69,125.23,2020-04-18,15:22:16,32, , M,3.6,MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES,2020-04-18 15:35,849329
5.65,126.54,2020-04-10,18:45:49,80, ,Mw,5.2,MINDANAO, PHILIPPINES,2020-04-11 06:41,846838
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of `earthquake.csv`?

Comment: Ok. Will add it in the post. @NYCCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your code, you were using date from a different for loop and that's why it picked up only the last date, you can use the Date from `gdf` too I'm guessing:

```
# for d in df['Date'].values:
#     date = d
for i in range(gdf.shape[0]): 
    ax = basemap.plot(figsize=(15,10)) 
    ax.axis('off')
    g = gdf.iloc[i].geometry           
    plt.plot(g.x, g.y, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
    title = 'Earthquakes in the ___ from 2008 to 2020'
    # Added this line
    date = gdf.iloc[i]['Date']
    dateInfo = str(date)
    plt.suptitle(title)
    # Changed this line
    plt.title(dateInfo)
    plt.savefig("earthquake_{0}.png".format(i))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: it works! Thank you! Also edited my original post, removed the "date" in "dateInfo accidentaly.